# Parsing regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm unable to parse a regex. I've tested it from regexpal.com and regex101.com (by setting the expression as `"(?:^csrf-token|;\s*csrf-token)=(.*?)(?:;|$)"` and the test string as "__ngDebug=false; csrf-token=b2ssOJ4jNOlPdmXAHn4CORPvFoO4Ngsupej25tdj") where it works.

The example is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxbLLcn/1/).

```js
function getCookie(name) {
   
    var s = "__ngDebug=false; csrf-token=b2ssOJ4jNOlPdmXAHn4CORPvFoO4Ngsupej25tdj";
    
    var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\s*"+ name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
    var result = regexp.exec(s);
    return (result === null) ? null : result[1];
}
alert(getCookie("csrf-token"));
```

If however `s` is `"csrf-token=b2ssOJ4jNOlPdmXAHn4CORPvFoO4Ngsupej25tdj"`, then it works fine. Please tell me what's wrong.

The expected output is `"b2ssOJ4jNOlPdmXAHn4CORPvFoO4Ngsupej25tdj"`, and there is no input (the string to be tested is 's').

Comment: Can you please be a bit clearer about what your expected output is? Also, when you say you can't "parse a regex" do you mean that you can't create a regex that does what you want it to?

Comment: If you're creating a regex from a string you need to escape any backslashes in the string. So `"\\s"` not `"\s"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
"|;\s*"
```

to

```
"|;\\s*"
    ^
```

The thing is, you are constructing the RegExp by passing in a string via the constructor, so you need to follow the rule of escaping in string literal. In JavaScript, `"\s"` is recognized as a single character string, with lowercase `s`. To specify `\`, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape `\s`

```
var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + "csrf-token" + "|;\\s*"+ "csrf-token" + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
                                                   ^
```